# Buy smartphone in US while visiting, fees in Europe

Tags: usa, europe, local-customs, greek-citizens

If I buy a smartphone ~700 USD from New York while travelling and come back to Greece, will there be fees while entering the country? The same phone costs about 1000 USD in Greece i am guessing from Customs.

Will there be some kind of check in the Customs?
Is there a specific amount of devices i can bring in the country(i might need 2)?

Will i have to declare what i bought in the US?

Comment: Yes, you will have to pay customs and taxes if you bring such a phone back to Greece. Except for that, you should however make sure that the phone you buy in the US will work properly in Europe. The cellular networks operate in different frequency bands and most smart phones come in different models for the US and European market.

Comment: I agree that he should declare it, but how can the custom prove that the device was not bought in Greece before the trip? Unboxed should be no problem.

Comment: If you travel with a new phone (or camera, laptop or whatever) you should have proof of buying in your home country or at least having registered it with customs in your home country.

Comment: @Matteo: Usually the burden of proof runs the other way.  You will be liable for customs duties unless *you* can prove that you bought it in Greece.

Comment: @Matteo so your life advice is to keep the law only when you are sure you'd get caught breaking it? o_O

Comment: @Matteo the chances of being caught are quite low if unboxed but that doesn’t mean it’s legal. You would be surprised as to how many little details can lead them in the right direction if they if they take an interest.

Comment: Be careful regarding the phone you buy. Many North American phone models do not support the necessary radio bands to work with 4G LTE in Europe or elsewhere in the world. An "expensive" phone like an iPhone or Samsung Galaxy should be fine, but you should research the specific phone you are interested in, before you spend the money.

Comment: Thank you fo your replies, @NateEldredge I think it is not possible to proove that i bought my current device from Greece. Also do these "customs duties" aply only for electronic devices?

Comment: @G.Siganos: Countries can apply customs duties to any and all goods.  It's not just electronic devices.